# Merge arbitrary amount of arrays, which may have shared elements, into a single, nested dictionary object that considers those shared elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, nested

I'm attempting to compile a big-picture "folder structure" dictionary object from multiple arrays that each contain folder name strings. Some of the folder/sub-folder names will be shared between the arrays and the nested dictionary object needs to reflect that.

When looping through each array of folder names to check if that "structure" already exists within the nested dictionary object, I can't seem to figure out how to account for previous folders and shared folders, considering there could be any number of folders in each array. How can you account for that arbitrary number without manually writing an endless amount of for-loops?

Here's a basic example of what the arrays could look like:

```
    var test1 = ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"];
    var test2 = ["sub1", "other"];
    var test3 = ["sub0", "misc"];
    var test4 = ["sub1", "sub2", "proj", "img"];
```

And here's the desired output based on the above example:

```
    var folder_structure = {
        "sub0": {
            "misc": {}
        },
        "sub1": {
            "sub2": {
                "sub3": {},
                "proj": {
                    "img": {}
                }
            },
            "other": {}
        },
    };
```

Comment: that seems a bit of strange that the structure of test1 is essentially different from the rest of arrays. test1 contains coma separated folder names whilst the rest of the arrays contain elements which are the actual strings. Is the fist array some kind of header-element or it's just has to be normalized to match the structure of the rest of arrays?

Comment: Yeah imagine that in python, those arrays would be joined to form a path, by using `os.path.join(test1)` - so therefore, they can vary in structure etc. It may be helpful to imagine that the root folder of all these paths is the same.

Comment: Whoops! I just realized what you're saying! I totally missed some quotations in the original question for `test1`. It's meant to be an array with 3 items. Good catch! I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do that in many ways. Here's my solution based on recursion:

```
var test1 = ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"];
var test2 = ["sub1", "other"];
var test3 = ["sub0", "misc"];
var test4 = ["sub1", "sub2", "proj", "img"];
const arrays = [test1, test2, test3, test4]; // just organizing all together

const addFolders = (root, folders) => {

    // let the base case for recursion be an empty folders array
    if (!folders.length) return root;

    const curFolderName = folders[0];
    const newFolder = root[curFolderName] || {};
    root[curFolderName] = newFolder;
    
    // recursive call:
    return addFolders(root[curFolderName], folders.slice(1));
}

// here you can also use an empty object as temp 
// result-storage and a simple for or forEach loop 
// instead of reduce method (up to your taste). 
const result = arrays.reduce((acc, folders) => addFolders(acc, folders) && acc, {}) 

console.dir(result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: I'm understanding everything here, but I'm not sure I understand the `&& acc` part in your `reduce` call. Would you mind explaining that? What would be most helpful is to show the `reduce` call passing in a standard function as compared to the arrow function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Andrew as I mentioned one can use a simple for loop instead of using reduce method here. The point is that in the least case one'd need an external scoped variable to store intermediate result while iterating through arrays[]. Converting to a standard function won't require much modification: `function(acc, folders) { return addFolders(acc, folders) && acc }`. And the `&& acc` trick is essentially equivalent to `function(acc, folders) { addFolders(acc, folders); return acc }`

Comment: Very helpful, perfect explainer, thank you!